# Pie Chart Center Text gets overlap with tooltip

Tags: angular, highcharts, pie-chart

I am using a Pie chart of HighChart lib. On hover over of pie, the center text is getting overlapped with the tooltip. Is there any solution to fix this?

[image]

link to stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/pie-chart-using-highcharts-er7kym?file=app%2Fhighcharts.service.ts

Answer (score 1):

Something in the settings was wrong, I created a similar chart from the demo and here the text no longer overlaps the tooltip.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: 0,
    plotShadow: false
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Browser<br>shares<br>2017',
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    y: 60
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      showInLegend: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      innerSize: '50%',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
        format: '<b><a (click)="helloFunc(point.name)">{point.name}</a></b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %bbb',
        style: {
          color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) ||
            'black',
        },
      },
      states: {
        hover: {
          brightness: 0,
          halo: {
            opacity: 1,
          },
        },
        select: {
          brightness: 0,
          halo: {
            opacity: 1,
          },
        },
      },
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: function() {
            let chart = this.series.chart;
            chart.title.attr({
              text: `<span style="color:#e43761;" class="dealer-title" data-oa-qa="donut-total-count-text">Total<br/><b>${this.y}</b></span>`,
            });
          },
          click: function() {
            let chart = this.series.chart;
            chart.title.attr({
              text: `<span style="color:#e43761;" class="dealer-title" data-oa-qa="donut-total-count-text">Total<br/><b>${this.y}</b></span>`,
            });
          },
          legendItemClick: function() {
            let chart = this.series.chart;
            chart.title.attr({
              text: `<span style="color:#e43761;" class="dealer-title" data-oa-qa="donut-total-count-text">Total<br/><b>${this.y}</b></span>`,
            });
            return false;
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Browser share',
    innerSize: '50%',
    data: [
      ['Chrome', 58.9],
      ['Firefox', 13.29],
      ['Internet Explorer', 13],
      ['Edge', 3.78],
      ['Safari', 3.42],
      {
        name: 'Other',
        y: 7.61,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    ]
  }]
});
```

Example recreated in Angular: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-86nmbd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your input @Sebastian Hajdus actually when I set the title on load of pie chart this overlap issue occurs. Otherwise it's working fine.chart: {
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBorderWidth: 0,
      plotShadow: false,
      events: {
        load: function () {
           
            let span = `<span style="color:#33383e;z-index:0" class="dealer-title">${100}<br/><b>Total</b></span>`;
            this.setTitle({ text: span, useHTML: true });
        }
    } https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-buzwdr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Got after doing some research got the answer.
just need to make useHTML as false.
this.series.chart.setTitle({ text: span, useHTML: false });

link to fiddle
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-buzwdr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts